# Download, Save, And Retrieve Image Path in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

i have a method where i download and save image from a given url, this method returns a File, then i use this File ( image ) to get it's path and use it to share this image.
My Test results where like this:

1. Samsung Note3 Neo 4.3: Worked
2. Emulator 2.2: Worked
3. Tablet 4.2: App crashes when method called
4. Emulator 3.1: App crashes when method called

My Method:

```
    private class getImgDownloadedPath extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
    private String urlImage;
    private String imageName;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    short max=100;

    public getImgDownloadedPath(Context context,String urlImage,String imageName){
          this.urlImage = urlImage;
          this.imageName = imageName;
          this.context = context;
          dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
          dialog.setTitle("Share");
          dialog.setMax(max);
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
          dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
          dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        dialog.show();


          }

    protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String filepath = null;
        File fileToReturn = null;
        try
        {   

            URL url = new URL(urlImage);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
            urlConnection.connect();                  
            String SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();  //.getAbsoluteFile();
            new File(SDCardRoot + "/Pictures/Pubit").mkdirs();
            String filename= imageName + ".png";   
            Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot + "/Pictures/myapp",filename);

            if(file.createNewFile()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
            }                 
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            int downloadedSize = 0;   
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
            {                 
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
                Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
            }             
            fileOutput.close();
            if(downloadedSize==totalSize){
                filepath=file.getPath();
                fileToReturn = file;
            }




        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            filepath=null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("filepath:"," "+fileToReturn.getPath()) ;
        dialog.dismiss();
        return fileToReturn;


    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(File filepath) 
    {

        Toast.makeText(activity,"This is url: " + filepath.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(filepath));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Image!"));

    }


}
```

Here is my Log Errors

```
    12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at me.devy.myapp.adapter.FeedListAdapter$getImgDownloadedPath.doInBackground(FeedListAdapter.java:360)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at me.devy.myapp.adapter.FeedListAdapter$getImgDownloadedPath.doInBackground(FeedListAdapter.java:1)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  ... 4 more
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896): Activity me.devy.myapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40c9d2f8 that was originally added here
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity me.devy.myapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40c9d2f8 that was originally added here
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:285)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:526)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at me.devy.myapp.adapter.FeedListAdapter$getImgDownloadedPath.onPreExecute(FeedListAdapter.java:302)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:549)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at me.devy.myapp.adapter.FeedListAdapter$2.onClick(FeedListAdapter.java:184)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-07 16:54:04.976: E/WindowManager(896):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 16:54:10.164: D/dalvikvm(896): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4729K, 24% free 18062K/23495K, paused 24ms+8ms
```

Could this problem be occured due to app can't somehow create Directories needed to store image ? if it's not the case please Help Thank you

Edit:

After applyingGreenapps's advice i did this:

```
    private class getImgDownloadedPath extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
    private String urlImage;
    private String imageName;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    short max=100;

    public getImgDownloadedPath(Context context,String urlImage,String imageName){
          this.urlImage = urlImage;
          this.imageName = imageName;
          this.context = context;
          dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
          dialog.setTitle("Pubit");
          dialog.setMax(max);
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
          dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
          dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        dialog.show();
        Log.i("Dialog:","Dialog is Shown");


          }

    protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("Do In Background:","Do In Background Started");
        String filepath = null;
        File fileToReturn = null;
        boolean success = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        try
        {   

            if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                Log.i("Phase 1:"," Available: True - Writable: True ");
                URL url = new URL(urlImage);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
                urlConnection.connect();                  
                String SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();  //.getAbsoluteFile();
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/Pubit");
                if(!f.isDirectory()) {
                    success = new File(SDCardRoot + "/Pictures/Pubit").mkdirs();
                    Log.i("MKDIRS:"," Creating /Pictures/Pubit ");
                }

                if (success) {
                    Log.i("Phase 2:"," MKDIRS Created /Pictures/Pubit ");
                    if (f.canWrite()) {
                        Log.i("Phase 3:"," /Pictures/Pubit is Writable ");
                        String filename= imageName + ".png";   
                        Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
                        File file = new File(SDCardRoot + "/Pictures/Pubit",filename);

                        if(file.createNewFile()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }                 
                        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                        int downloadedSize = 0;   
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bufferLength = 0;
                        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {                 
                            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
                            downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
                            Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
                        }             
                        fileOutput.close();
                        if(downloadedSize==totalSize){
                            filepath=file.getPath();
                            fileToReturn = file;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Folder: Pictures/Pubit Can't write", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("Cause Of Error:","Folder: Pictures/Pubit Can't write");
                    }
                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Error Creating Folders", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("Cause Of Error:","Error Creating Folders");

                }
            } 
            else if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
                // Storage is only readable
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Available: True - Writable - False ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Cause Of Error:","Available: True - Writable - False ");
            }
            else {
                // Storage is neither readable nor writeable
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Available: False - Writable - False ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Cause Of Error:","Available: False - Writable - False ");
            }

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.i("Problem is Malformed Url:","Starting -------------------------");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Problem is Malformed Url:","Ending -------------------------");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Problem is IO Exception: ","Starting -------------------------");
            filepath=null;
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Problem is IO Exception: ","Ending -------------------------");
        }

        Log.i("filepath:"," "+fileToReturn.getPath()) ;
        dialog.dismiss();
        return fileToReturn;


    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(File filepath) 
    {   
        Log.i("filepath value:","Value of filepath is: " + filepath);
        if (filepath == null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Can't Share, File is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.i("Cause Of Error:","Can't Share, File is null");
        }
        else{
        Toast.makeText(activity,"This is url: " + filepath.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(filepath));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Image!"));
        }

    }


}
```

And still won't work Same problem any advices ??

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 16:54:01.754: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at me.devy.myapp.adapter.FeedListAdapter$getImgDownloadedPath.doInBackground(FeedListAdapter.java:360)` what is line 360?

Comment: it's this line:    Log.i("filepath:"," "+fileToReturn.getPath());

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line, run in debug an examine filePath and fileToReturn.  One of them is null.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I did, and they Are Both Null, What's The problem ??

Comment: Before you start your asynctask you should check if the external storage directory exists and is writable. Do not continue if it isnt. After that check if Pictures/Pubit exist and only use mkdirs() if they don't. Check the return value of mkdirs and don't continu if false. Check if your directory is writable. Only after doing all these check you could start the asynctask.

Comment: @greenapps i did what you told me but i have the same error, Look at my Edit, thank you

Comment: No you did not do that. As all the code to check is still in doInBackground. Take all that ckecking code out. And do the checks BEFORE you start the asynctask. At the moment you introduced new errors as a Toast() in doInBackground is not allowed. So please adapt your code first. And add an extra parameter to getImgDownloadedPath for the destination dir.

Comment: Thank you @greenapps i solved The problem By Getting the checks out, and now it's working on the 2 emulators and my note 3 but the tablet has a problem with creating files and folders with other apps, Thank you again for your Great Answers